# How to update date field dynamically daily

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow

There is a number of days open field that counts the days until the ticket is closed. Let's say a ticket is opened today and the days open field counts until the ticket is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following formula:

```
=DATEDIF([StartDateColumn], [TODAYColumn],"d")
```

Or simply

```
 =[TODAYColumn]- [StartDateColumn]
```

Maybe you can use [Calculated Field Formulas.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
Screenshot attached. Because the function Today cannot be used in a calculated column, you need to create a field with the Today value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, for prompt respond could you Look at my attached scrren shot .Thanks again

Comment: @Sai where's the screenshot?

Comment: Did you look at M. Qassas ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way I achieved this goal using powershell.

https://github.com/ggjames/sharepoint/blob/master/ForceUpdateListItems.ps1

Instruction

## 1. create a column in your list as [Today's Date]

## 2. Setup this powershell into task scheduler, and set the trigger frequecy as you like

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://abc.com/sites/web/  #name of web app 
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["MyList"]    #name of your list
foreach($SPItem in $SPList.Items)
{
    $DateToday = (Get-date).Date               #get today's date
    $SPItem["Today's Date"] = $DateToday       #update today's date into your column which used to store the today's date.    
    $SPItem.SystemUpdate() #Will force an item be updated, trigger all the calculated columns in this item to be recalculated as well.
}
```